# How do I add new Headers to Flutter plugin iOS project?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, podfile

I'm working on a Flutter plugin on the iOS side. Initially the generated code for the plugin includes:

`MyPlugin.h
MyPlugin.m`

I have added a new class in the same directory as the plugin source files:

`MyClass.h
MyClass.m`

When I include `MyClass.h` within `MyPlugin.m`, everything works fine.

When I include `MyClass.h` within `MyPlugin.h`, the build fails and complains that `MyClass.h` cannot be found.

What do I have to do to expose `MyClass.h` to `MyPlugin.h`?

I tried configuring the plugin "target" to include `MyClass.h` under the "Project" section of "Headers" but that didn't help.

Then I dug into the file system a bit and I see that the existing `MyPlugin.h` is being symlinked `example/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/my_plugin/MyPlugin.h` and also `example/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/my_plugin/MyPlugin.h`.  However, my `MyClass.h` header is not symlinked to those locations and I have no idea why.

I'm guessing there is something I have to update about the plugin's Podfile? But I'm not sure...

Comment: Could you post your current podfile?

Answer (score 1):

It was pointed out to me that my version of Cocoapods (1.3.1) might be the problem.

I upgraded Cocoapods to 1.5.0 and ran `pod install` from the example project and the issues seem to be resolved.